# Unit testing vue component, using vue-cli, can't test parent methods?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm running into this problem that I can't figure out and looking around can't seem to find anyone asking the same questions...

So, here's my working code:

***main.js:***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

window.Vue = Vue

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  methods: {
    greetings: function () {
      return 'good morning'
    }
  },
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

***router/index.js:***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Configurations from '@/components/Configurations'

Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/configs',
      name: 'Configurations',
      component: Configurations
    }
  ]
})
```

***App.vue:***

```
<template>
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App"
};
</script>
```

***Configurations.vue:***

```
<template>
<span>{{greetings}}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "configurations",
  data() {
    return {
      greetings: ""
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    this.greetings = this.$root.greetings();
  }
};
</script>
```

When I run this, it displays a page with the words "good morning" on it. Nothing else. As you can see, the greetings message is defined on the main.js file, because in this scenario I'd like a message to be displayed on all components, ie: a copyright note. So I set the message on the common ancestor to all my components.

From my understanding, to call a method from a "parent" component, you use this.$root.yourMethod() to call it.

Now, the problem is, that if I wish to run a unit-test for the Configurations component, I get an error which leads me to believe that the way I have things set up, I cannot test the this.$root.greetings() because something tells me the testing environment is unaware of the parent-child relationship between the components.

So, when I run:

```
cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run
```

Having the following test file set up:

***Configurations.spec.js***:

```
import Configurations from '@/components/Configurations'
import Vue from 'vue'

describe('Configurations.vue', () => {
  it('should display a greetings message', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(Configurations)
    const ConfigurationsComponent = new Constructor().$mount()
    expect(ConfigurationsComponent.greetings).to.not.be.undefined;
  })
})
```

I get:

```
> 16 10 2018 09:28:35.184:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at
> http://0.0.0.0:3000/ 16 10 2018 09:28:35.191:INFO [launcher]:
> Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency 16 10 2018
> 09:28:35.204:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS 16 10 2018
> 09:28:40.977:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0)]: Connected on
> socket WnDl-mQqmNZQOfyzAAAA with id 10303480 ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]:
> Error in created hook: "TypeError:  is not a constructor (evaluating
> 'this.$root.greetings()')"
```

(followed by more lines that stack-overflow won't let me post because they contain too many links)

Now, if I were to change

```
this.greetings = this.$root.greetings()
```

To:

```
this.greetings = "good morning";
```

In the ***Configurations.vue*** file, and then run the test command again, I'd get:

```
> 16 10 2018 09:48:43.174:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at
> http://0.0.0.0:3000/ 16 10 2018 09:48:43.180:INFO [launcher]:
> Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency 16 10 2018
> 09:48:43.555:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS 16 10 2018
> 09:48:49.228:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0)]: Connected on
> socket o8BQ24wv1QX26SAZAAAA with id 53463701
> 
>   Configurations.vue
>     √ should display a greetings message
>
> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.024 secs / 0.017 secs)
>
> TOTAL: 1 SUCCESS
```

(followed by some other information that's irrelevant)

So, how can I run a unit-test for a component that contains calls to this.$root methods?

Any help is appreciated.

- Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should (nearly) never call something from a parent component.

You have 2 possibilities:
1. Use a vuex store and save your data there. Then every component in need can access it by a store getter.
2. Provide the needed data as props to your child components.

Because the props thing gets very quick messy a suggest to use the store.

If you do so your tests will become much clearer and easier to read.

Simple test with a mocked store (just to show how things could be):

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue()
    wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      mocks: {
        $store: {
          getters: {
            'copyright': 'MyCopyright text'
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })

  it('should display copyright text', () => {
    expect(wrapper.text('MyCopyright text')).toBe(true) 
  })
})
```

Comment: I understand. But for very simple things is there no other option? I'll give vuex a try but seems a bit overkill for something simple.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works fine up to the point where I decide to test it:

Now the same problem occurs but now its complaining about this.$store rather than this.$root

My testing environment is just not aware of main.js apparently...

Comment: Your environment is not supposed to know your main.js in unit tests. I updated my answer with a simple test mocking the store. It is using jest as test runner.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks again.

Actually, after you suggested vuex I went searching for this topic again and found my answers.

This helped me in the end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542697/error-in-unit-test-vuejs-component-with-vuex

The store is now available within my spec file which is the key I was missing and its very similar to your suggestion.

While I didn't test your code, I'm still accepting your answer for leading me in the right tracks.

Seems I still have quite a bit to learn with unit-testing and vue. THanks!

Comment: The most difficult step is always the first one! ;)